# How do I add an ID for an input tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add an ID for an input tag that doesn't have any ID or class? Is it  possible like this:

```
<div id="1">hey all</div>
<input type="text" name="txt" />

<script>
    document.querySelector('input[type="search"]').id = 'sinput';
    document.getElementById("sinput").addEventListener("keypress", function() {   
        document.getElementById("1").style.display ="none";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: typeing `<input  id="fish" type="text" name="txt"  />`

Comment: Well for a start... your input type is `text` but in your selector you're attempting to get `search`...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I haven't seen a answer that tells you the problem with your current source code and it doesn't appear you have acknowledged my comment so maybe you showing you a working snippet will do.

The only thing you need to change is the `type` attribute from `text` to `search` to match your selector `'input[type="search"]'` or change your selector to match the input type `'input[type="text"]'`.

> Change input `type`=**search**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="search"]').id = 'sinput';
document.getElementById("sinput").addEventListener("keypress", function() {   
        document.getElementById("1").style.display ="none";
});
```

```html
<div id="1">hey all</div>
<input type="search" name="txt" />
```

---

> Or change the selector `input[type="`**text**`"]`

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').id = 'sinput';
document.getElementById("sinput").addEventListener("keypress", function() {   
        document.getElementById("1").style.display ="none";
});
```

```html
<div id="1">hey all</div>
<input type="text" name="txt" />
```

If you have any questions feel free to comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much .
it's work with me in new project 
but not for this project 
" i want show all table when i press enter for input "

this my website project
http://sci.mu.edu.iq/?page_id=3347
pls help me

Comment: this for code 

<style>
tbody {
display: none;
}

</style>

<script>
document.querySelector('input[type="search"]').id = 'sinput';
document.getElementById("sinput").addEventListener("keypress", function() {   
        document.getElementById("tbody").style.display ="block";
});
</script>